# How to convert spreadsheetworkbook to Microsoft Excel Workbook through C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0

Hi Below is my code but it is throwing exception at run time.

```
var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memorystream, 
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

WorkbookPart workbookpart = doc.WorkbookPart;

//Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is 
//referenced
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

//Below line throwing exception for casting.
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)workbookpart.Workbook;
```

How can I achieve this casting?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?  Why are you casting it, the `Workbook` property of a `WorkbookPart` is already of type `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook` according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.workbookpart.workbook(v=office.14).aspx).  Is `Excel` a namespace alias, or is `Excel` a separate namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to convert the file by way of a cast.  You need to write the contents of your `MemoryStream` to a file, and then open that file with the `Excel.Application` instance.